# Asynctask for downloading data and saving into variable?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have the downloading part done using Retriever.getCourses(username,password), but the following code gives me an error later on saying Values.Courses is set to null. I think I wrote the AsyncTask incorrectly.Thanks!

```
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private final String muser;
    private final String mPassword;
    private boolean checked;
    private ArrayList<Course> crs;
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Teacher> tc;

    UserLoginTask(String user, String password) {
        muser = user;
        mPassword = password;

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

        try {

                return Retriever.logInTest(muser, mPassword);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }

        // TODO: register the new account here.
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);

        if (success) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = Login.this.getSharedPreferences("Login",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString("Username", muser);
            editor.putString("Password", mPassword);

            crs = Retriever.getCourses(muser, mPassword);

            Values.courses = crs;
            editor.commit();

            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
            mPasswordView.requestFocus();
        }

    }
    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);
    }

}
```

---

```
public class UserCourseTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList>{

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private ArrayList<Course> courses;

    public UserCourseTask(String user, String pass)
    {
        username = user;
        password = pass;
    }


    protected ArrayList doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        try{
            courses = Retriever.getCourses(username,password);
            return courses;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", e);
        }
        return courses;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Course> result)
    {
        setCourses(result);
    }
}
```

---

In Grades Fragment.  `courses.size()` is causing the error

```
@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_grades, container, false);
    ListView yourListView = (ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.listview);
    ArrayList<Course> courses = Values.courses;
    for(int i = 0; i<courses.size();i++)
    {
        if(courses.get(i).getSubject().equals("Lunch"))
        {
            courses.remove(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    yourListView.setAdapter(new CourseAdapter(rootview.getContext(),courses));
    yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Values.assignments = Values.courses.get(position).getAssignments();
            Values.assingmentsclass = Values.courses.get(position).getSubject();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Scrnassign.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });


    return rootview;

}
```

Comment: I'm assuming `Values.courses` is some static variable? You shouldn't use static variables to pass data between classes in Android

Comment: Also, this shouldn't compile because your AsyncTask isn't defined as returning `ArrayList<Course>`

Comment: what should I use instead of static variables?

Comment: Am asynchronous callback to your Activity via an interface. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35210468/2308683

Comment: And it still says `Values.courses` is null because an AsyncTask doesn't execute and immediately get the result. Hence the Async part of the class... You have to wait until the doInBackground and onPostExecute are over before using your variable.

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense, but where would I set the variable? I thought I would put it in onPostExecute because it was finished with doInBackground?

Comment: You do set in onPostExecute, but the problem is that it will be null from the class you executed the AsyncTask from until the AsyncTask finishes. I assume that's what you mean by it's still null? Otherwise, check if your Receiver method is returning null.

Comment: so what I'm doing is that I'm putting the arraylist of courses into a listview, which is showing an error because the arraylist is null. I am calling this AsyncTask from within another AsyncTask, and when I didn't use an asynctask for the courses it worked perfectly but  the ui froze while it was getting the courses, so i don't think the retriever is what is causing the error.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the full path of the data flow. Why are there two AsyncTask?

Comment: one of them is for logging in, and the other one is for getting the courses

Comment: Please edit your question with a [mcve]. I would like to see where and how you are getting null

Comment: You should be executing the courses and teachers tasks inside of the MainActivity instead of the Login Activity or its AsyncTask OnPostExecute

Comment: I've made the amount of code in your question smaller, but it still is not complete or verifiable. Please include at least one of the `Retriever` methods.

Answer (score 0):

inside doInBackground you have returned null, instead return courses. What you return there will be sent as a parameter to onPostExecute

Comment: I guess that is because the AsyncTask is configured for Void, Void, Void. When the return type of a method is Void,there is probably not much else you can return besides null.

Comment: @Jägermeister is correct. You should change following two things:

extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,ArrayList>

also, return courses;

Comment: @Jägermeister Then how does the parameter of onPostExecute have an Arraylist for the parameter?

Comment: Thank you, but I changed the code to that and it is still saying Values.courses is null? I updated the original question

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments and referred to [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35210468/2308683), an AsyncTask, is asynchronous, hence the name. In other words, you are not guaranteed a value for your variables that you assign within `onPostExecute` and you shouldn't use those variables in your Activities / Fragments until you are sure they have a value.

The way to appropriately handle the asynchronous nature and ensure you have a value is to use a callback function. From that link, I defined a generic interface to pass results around between classes.

```
public interface AsyncResponse<T> {
    void onResponse(T response);
}
```

You can define your AsyncTasks as such for login

```
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private final String muser;
    private final String mPassword;
    private final AsyncResponse<Boolean> callback;

    public UserLoginTask(String user, String password, AsyncResponse<Boolean> callback) {
        this.muser = user;
        this.mPassword = password;
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        boolean login = false;

        // TODO: Some network operation
        try {
            login = doLogin(this.muser, this.mPassword);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("LoginError", e.getMessage());
        }

        return login;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean response) {
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.onResponse(response);
        }
    }
}
```

---

And to get the courses

```
public class GetCoursesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Course>> {

    private final String username;
    private final String password;
    private final AsyncResponse<List<Course>> callback;

    public GetCoursesTask(String username, String password, AsyncResponse<List<Course>> callback) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Course> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<Course>();

        // TODO: Some network operation
        try {
            courses.addAll(getCourses(username, password));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("GetCoursesError", e.getMessage());
        }

        return courses;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Course> response) {
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.onResponse(response);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the simple `onPostExecute` simply forwards along the response to the interface defined in the constructor.

Now, in your Login Activity, you can use code like this

```
UserLoginTask loginTask = new UserLoginTask(
        "username",
        mPasswordView.getText().toString(),
        new AsyncResponse<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Boolean response) {
                if (response) {
                    // TODO: Save data in SharedPreference
                    Intent loginIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, CoursesActivity.class);
                    loginIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(loginIntent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    mPasswordView.setError("Incorrect Password");
                    mPasswordView.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        }
);
loginTask.execute();
```

And in the Courses Fragment

```
private CourseAdapter adapter;
private ListView yourListView;
private ProgressDialog progress;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_grades, container, false);

    this.yourListView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listview);
    this.adapter = new CourseAdapter(getContext(), new ArrayList<Course>());
    this.yourListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    this.progress = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    this.progress.setMessage("Loading Courses...");

    fetchCourses();

    return v;
}

private void fetchCourses() {
    this.progress.show();

    GetCoursesTask getCoursesTask = new GetCoursesTask(
            "username",
            "password",
            new AsyncResponse<List<Course>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(List<Course> response) {
                    adapter.clear();
                    adapter.addAll(response);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    progress.hide();
                }
            });
    getCoursesTask.execute();
}
```