# Getting the calling fragment within an asynchronous task

Tags: android, rest, android-fragments, android-asynctask, androidhttpclient

## Aim

In a fragment, I have a search bar which looks for online news about what the user typed. I would want to display these news (title + description + date of publication + ... etc.) in the GUI, as vertical blocks.

## Implementation

### Explanations

In the fragment, within the search event handling, I instanciated an asynchronous task and execute it with the good URL REST API I use to do the search.

In the asynchronous task, I make use of this REST API (thanks to the URL and some required parameters as an authorization key, etc.). When my asynchronous task gets answered, it must update the fragment's GUI (*i.e.:* it must vertically stack GUI blocks containing the titles, descriptions, etc. of the got news).

### Sources

You will find sources in the last part of this question.

## My question

In the asynchronous task (more precisely: in its function that is executed after having got the answer), I don't know how to get the calling fragment. How to do this?

## Sources

### Fragment part

```
private void getAndDisplayNewsForThisKeywords(CharSequence keywords) {
    keywords = Normalizer.normalize(keywords, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
    new NetworkUseWorldNews().execute("https://api.currentsapi.services/v1/search?keyword=" + keywords + "&language=en&country=US");
}
```

### Asynchronous task part

```
    public class NetworkUseWorldNews extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String[] urls) {
            StringBuilder string_builder = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                HttpsURLConnection https_url_connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                https_url

_connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            https_url_connection.setDoOutput(false);
            https_url_connection.setUseCaches(false);
            https_url_connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "XXX");

            InputStream input_stream = https_url_connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader buffered_reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input_stream));
            String line;
            while((line = buffered_reader.readLine()) != null) {
                string_builder.append(line);
            }
            buffered_reader.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return string_builder.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            JSONObject news_response_http_call = new JSONObject(result);

            switch(news_response_http_call.getString("status")) {
                case "ok":
                    JSONArray news = news_response_http_call.getJSONArray("news");
                    for(int i = 0; i < news.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject a_news = news.getJSONObject(i);
                        String title = a_news.getString("title");
                        String description = a_news.getString("description");
                        String date_of_publication = a_news.getString("published");
                        String url = a_news.getString("url");
                        String image = a_news.getString("image");
                        System.out.println(title + ": " + date_of_publication + "\n" + image + "\n" + url + "\n" + description);

                        WorldNewsFragment world_news_fragment = ...;
                    }
                    break;
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to get the current fragment?

Comment: I want to get the fragment which executed the asynchronous task. I don't know what "current" means: do you have the same definition than mine? Or does it mean "the fragment which is currently executed by Android on the user's phone"? The latter could change, since the (network!) task is asynchronous: imagine the user changes of fragment 5 seconds after having executed the asynchronous task in the other fragment (this task ends after > 5 seconds): this one should be executed, but the current fragment will and it would be a problem for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am right, you want to **update View** of your caller **`Fragment`**. if `FragmentA` called service then `FragmentA` should be update.

However the approach you are asking is wrong. Instead of getting caller Fragment in your AsyncTask response. You should do it with [Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19405498/6891563).

So now you will need to pass callback in AsyncTask. So instead of posting full code, here are already [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26202602/6891563) with this problem.

Finally your calling syntax will look like.

```
NetworkUseWorldNews task = new NetworkUseWorldNews(new OnResponseListener() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String result) {
        // Either get raw response, or get response model 
    }
});

task.execute();
```

Actually I am still very unclear about your question. Let me know in comments if you have more queries.

**Must checkout**

- [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) or [Volley](https://github.com/google/volley) for calling Rest APIs
- [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) for parsing JSON response automatically to models

Comment: Indeed! I wanted to ask another question after this one, in order to separate my data (the asynchronous task) from my view (my fragment's class). Thus I read your answer with a lot of pleasure, since you anticipated my next question! Thank you!

Comment: Nope you understood it perfectly and answered it perfectly.

Comment: Check linked libraries also.

Comment: Are you sure you can pass this listener as a constructor's param?

Comment: Yes, are you facing any problem? Did you go through the answer I linked. I did not post all changes to be made in your code, so check linked answer. You will create constructor in your AsyncTask class.

Comment: Well `OnResponseListener` doesn't exist. The only listeners I could use are: `OnFragmentInteractionListener` and another one. Both aren't useful

Comment: Bro, ohh, you are very new!, can you please go through answer I linked. you will create callback interface, it is not there already.

Comment: Oh, I thought `AsyncTask` class provided such an interface! Thanks again